# CSS set background-image of an element with an url from the element

Tags: html, css

I want to set the background-image property of my element, so that the background image equals the "href" attribute of the element.
For example:

HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.someimagesite.com/thumbnailimage.jpg" href="https://www.someimagesite.com/largeimage.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="" class="image">
```

CSS: (i thought maybe something like this)

```
img {
width:156px !important;
height:auto !important;
background-image: <href> !important;
}
```

Hope you understand what i want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img {
  width:156px !important;
  height:auto !important;
  background-image: attr(href) !important;
}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest it, but was looking up the support for it, which is rather low https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: @BiepbotVonStirling yes... Otherwise javascript is only the option

Answer (score 0):

If your generating Img tag dynamically then add style attribute

```
<img src="https://www.someimagesite.com/thumbnailimage.jpg" style="background-image: url(https://www.someimagesite.com/largeimage.jpg);" href="https://www.someimagesite.com/largeimage.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="" class="image">
```

Comment: I can't do that because i am building a chrome extension for a site, which is not mine.

Comment: Then use JavaScript.